# How do I cleanly shut down NodeOS?

Tags: nodeos

I'd like to cleanly shut down NodeOS so that the next time I start it, I don't have to --resync. How do I do that?

Edit: Just to clarify the purpose of what might seem like an extremely obvious question/answer, I was getting prompted to resync after using `pkill` to terminate nodeOS...or, so I thought - due to a bug in my code, nodeOS was being killed by the termination of a JVM (long story) - the answer to this question helped me trace that issue - it's resolved now and everything is awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pkill nodeos`
or just 
`kill <PID>` where pid is nodeos's pid.

basically do **not** do: `kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: Wait, what? So, I create and start a blockchain...I'd like to be able to stop it such that when I start it again, I don't have to add the --replay parameter.

What does your answer have to do with stopping blockchains at all?

Comment: misread your question, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `ctr+c` or just kill the process, in either case you won’t need a resync.

Answer (score 0):

pidof is good.
use following command.

```
$ kill \`pidof nodeos\`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find out what port `nodeos` is running on.

`$ pgrep nodeos | xargs printf " -p %d" | xargs lsof -Pani`

Then, kill the process with:

`$ pkill nodeos`